# CSS text-align: justify not working for span/strong

Tags: css, text-align, css-hyphens

I have a problem with css. This is my HTML code

```
<p><strong>Loremipsumdolorsitg, consetetur sadipscing: </strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. </p>
```

```
p {
 text-align: justify;
 hyphens: auto;
}
```

But it seems so:

[image]

It works in p perfect. Text had full width with hyphens but not in strong. Space in  between words ist to big. How can i fix it?

I did test it with

`display: inline` and `text-align: justify;` for strong but it also doesnt work

Comment: Looks like the text in the `<strong>` was too long to fit on one line, so it made a best-guess on where to place a hyphen to break up the word, leaving it with just Loremipsumdolorsitg, consetetur and sa- to fit on the line, and the justification algorithm meant that it was that spread out. Just as a test can you try adding a `&shy;` like `sadipsc&shy;ing`, it should break the word there instead and not look as bad.

Comment: Emboldened characters take up more space so that text couldn’t quite fit on one line whereas it managed to do so when no strong involved. If you don’t like where it hyphenates then do as @dan suggests, but be cautious as it’s not obvious to me where the best break point would be for someone trying to read this.

Comment: use real words – your example is unrealistic

Answer (score 0):

`text-align: justify;` will justify the words automatically (left, center, right) for the first line as it cannot fit within the available width, hence why you are seeing the gaps in your text. Then it believes it has done it's job and the rest of the paragraph is as normal.

Removing the `text-align: justify;` and just keeping the `hyphens: auto;` will still apply hyphens to the title, and if you are wanting to break to a new line between the title and the main paragraph you could simply add a `<br>` tag immediately after the `</strong>`.

So something like:

```
<p><strong>Loremipsumdolorsitg, consetetur sadipscing: </strong><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. </p>
```

If you are certain you require some kind of text aligning, you could alter `text-align: justify;` to `text-align: left;`

If however you are wanting the title to exclude hiphens, but you would like the rest of the text to have hiphens, and be inline, then you need to break your title out of the paragraph like this:

```
<strong>title</strong><p>rest of paragraph</p>
```

and in your CSS:

```
p {
 text-align: left;
 hyphens: auto;
 display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finaly i used `&shy;` for manual breaks. It seems that these strong-tags are poorly defined where words are hyphenated.